# Central Limit Theorem: Sample means do not follow a normal distribution

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, statistics, simulation

## The Problem

---

Good evening.

I am learning about the Central Limit Theorem. As practice, I ran simulations in an attempt to find the mean of a fair die (I know, a toy problem).

I took 4000 samples, and in each sample I rolled a die 50 times (screenshot of the code at the bottom). For each of these 4000 samples I computed the mean. Then, I plotted these 4000 sample means in a histogram (with bin size 0.03) using `matplotlib`.

Here is the result:

[image]

## Question

---

Why aren't the sample means normally distributed given that the conditions for CLT (sample size >= 30) were respected?

Specifically, why does the histogram look like **two** normal distributions superimposed on top of each other? More intriguingly, why does the "outer" distribution look "discrete" with empty spaces occurring at **regular** intervals?

It almost seems like the result is off in a systematic way.

All help is greatly appreciated. I am very lost.

## Supplementary Code

---

The code I used to generate the 4000 sample means.

```
"""
Take multiple samples of dice rolls. For
each sample, compute the sample mean.

With the sample means, plot a histogram.
By the Central Limit Theorem, the sample
means should be normally distributed.

"""

sample_means = []

num_samples = 4000

for i in range(num_samples):
    # Large enough for CLT to hold
    num_rolls = 50
    
    sample = []
    for j in range(num_rolls):
        observation = random.randint(1, 6)
        sample.append(observation)
    
    sample_mean = sum(sample) / len(sample)
    sample_means.append(sample_mean)
```

Comment: With num_rolls equal to 50, each possible mean will be a fraction with denominator 50. To correctly grab all possible values, you could use `bins=np.arange(3.01, 4, 0.02)`

Comment: @JohanC thank you for the reply, that makes a lot of sense. I tried starting from `3.01` but nothing changes. That said, I increased the number of rolls to 500 (up from 50) and the distribution is a lot closer to normal now. I think you are on to something!

Comment: The problem is entirely with the locations of discrete outcomes in your histogram, not with the CLT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `num_rolls` equals `50`, each possible mean will be a fraction with denominator `50`. So, in reality, you are looking at a discrete distribution.

To create a histogram of a discrete distribution, the bin boundaries are best placed nicely in-between the values. Using a step size of `0.03`, some bin boundaries will coincide with the values, putting the double of values into one bin compared to its neighbor. Moreover, due to subtle floating point rounding problems, the result can become unpredictable when values and boundaries coincide.

Here is some code to illustrate what is going on:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

sample_means = []
num_samples = 4000

for i in range(num_samples):
    num_rolls = 50
    sample = []
    for j in range(num_rolls):
        observation = random.randint(1, 6)
        sample.append(observation)

    sample_mean = sum(sample) / len(sample)
    sample_means.append(sample_mean)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 8))

random_y = np.random.rand(len(sample_means))
for (ax0, ax1), step in zip(axs, [0.03, 0.02]):
    bins = np.arange(3.01, 4, step)
    ax0.hist(sample_means, bins=bins)
    ax0.set_title(f'step={step}')
    ax0.vlines(bins, 0, ax0.get_ylim()[1], ls=':', color='r')  # show the bin boundaries in red
    ax1.scatter(sample_means, random_y, s=1)  # show the sample means with a random y
    ax1.vlines(bins, 0, 1, ls=':', color='r')  # show the bin boundaries in red
    ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(3, 4, 0.02))
    ax1.set_xlim(3.0, 3.3)  # zoom in to region to better see the ins
    ax1.set_title('bin boundaries between values' if step == 0.02 else 'chaotic bin boundaries')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram of sample means]

PS: Note that the code would run much, much faster if instead of Python lists, the code would work completely with numpy.

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply and instructive plots (you are an absolute jupyter magician); you make a lot of sense and I learnt a lot!